# printing the result of my JS function

Tags: javascript, html

This is the code of my function, im trying to put the result of the function in partie 2 and not partie 4, and I also have troubles understanding how to stop making it repeat the result. I only want 1 line of result everytime an input is entered.

Here is the picture of the function in action

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
    <script type="text/javascript"></script>
    <title>Travail pratique 3</title>
    <h1>Travail pratique #3</h1>   
    <h2>Identification</h2>
   </p>
    <p>Publi&eacute; sur mon tp3 &aacute; la DESI </p>
    <style>
    #toggleThis{
        margin-bottom: 5px;
        background: #e5eecc;
        border: solid;
        border:#c3c3c3;
        border: 1px;
        }

        #partie4{
            background-color: #e5eecc;
            margin-top:50px;
            display:none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Partie 1: Affichage et animation des images</h2> 
<div id="radiobuttons">
<label><input name="vf" type="radio" onclick="changeImage('http://i.imgur.com/0zfjKQi.jpg')" value="0" checked/>Salade</label>
<br>
<label><input name="vf" type="radio" onclick="changeImage('http://i.imgur.com/OixGjjE.jpg')" value="1"/>Spaghetti</label><br>
<label><input name="vf" type="radio" onclick="changeImage('http://i.imgur.com/gASTpLX.jpg')" value="2"/>Creme glacee</label>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
</div>
<img id="food">

<h2>Partie 2: Affichage dans la page web contr&ocirc;l&eacute; par JavaScript</h2>

<form>
Nom: <input type="text" name="fullname"><br><br>
Niveau (1 &aacute; 6): <input type="text" name="niveau">
<input type="button" value="Afficher partie 2">
</form> 

    <div class="Affichage">

    </div>
    <h2>Partie 3: Formulaire de conversion</h2>
Valeur:<input type="text" id="value" name="valeur" value="0">
<p id="result">Resultat ici</p>
<button type="button" id="inchToCm" onclick="pvc('inch')">Pouces vers cm</button>
<button type="button" id="cmtoInch" onclick="pvc('cm')">CM vers pouces</button>
<button type="button" id="celciusToFarenheit" onclick="pvc('celc')">Celcius vers
    Farenheit</button>
<button type="button" id="farenheitToCelcius" onclick="pvc('fahr')">Farenheit vers Celcius</button>
    <div id="toggleThis">
    <h2>Partie 4: JQuery (cliquez ici)</h2>
    <div id="partie4">Voici le contenu de la partie 4, cliquez de nouveau sur le titre</div>
<script>
    function changeImage(imgUrl){
  document.querySelector("#food").src=imgUrl;
}   

</script>
<script>
function do_stuff() {
  var x = document.getElementsByName("fullname")[0].value;
  var y = document.getElementsByName("niveau")[0].value;
  if (parseInt(y)>=1 && parseInt(y)<=6){
    document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Bonjour "+x));
    document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Niveau='"+y+"'"));
  }
  else {
    var p = document.createElement('P');
    p.style.color = "red";
    p.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Erreur le niveau doit etre en 1 et 6"));
    document.body.appendChild(p);
  }
}

document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  for(let input of document.getElementsByTagName("input")) {
    if (input.type == "button") { input.addEventListener( "click", do_stuff ); }
  }
}, false );
        </script>

    <script>

function pvc(val) {
  var input = document.getElementById("value").value;
  var result = document.getElementById("result");

  if (val == 'inch') {
    result.innerHTML = input / 0.39370;
  } else if (val == 'cm') {
    result.innerHTML = input * 0.39370;
  } else if (val == 'celc') {
    result.innerHTML = 9 / 5 + 32;
  } else if (val == 'fahr') {
    result.innerHTML = (input - 32) * 5 / 9;
  }
}
</script>







</body>




</html>
```

Anyone has an idea how to do that?

Comment: If your code appends to the body then it will always be at the bottom of the screen, i.e. Partie 4. You should show your HTML if you want a detailed answer.

Comment: It would be better to post the HTML code here.

Comment: is it possible to append to a div id or something ?

Comment: yes I have thanks for the help man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `JQuery`. Why don't you use it. Just change the function **do_stuff** with this:

```
function do_stuff() {
  var x = $("input[name=fullname]").val();
  var y = $("input[name=niveau]").val();
if (parseInt(y)>=1 && parseInt(y)<=6){
    $( ".Affichage" ).html( "<p>Bonjour" + x + " Niveau=" + y + "'</p>");
    $( ".Affichage" ).css("color", "black");
} else {
    $( ".Affichage" ).html( "<p>Erreur le niveau doit etre en 1 et 6</p>");
    $( ".Affichage" ).css("color", "red");
}
}
```

Hope i got it right. And here is a working snippet.

```js
function changeImage(imgUrl) {
  document.querySelector("#food").src = imgUrl;
}
function do_stuff() {
  var x = $("input[name=fullname]").val();
  var y = $("input[name=niveau]").val();
  if (parseInt(y)>=1 && parseInt(y)<=6){
    $( ".Affichage" ).html( "<p>Bonjour" + x + " Niveau=" + y + "'</p>");
    $( ".Affichage" ).css("color", "black");

  }
  else {
    $( ".Affichage" ).html( "<p>Erreur le niveau doit etre en 1 et 6</p>");
    $( ".Affichage" ).css("color", "red");
  }
}

document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  for(let input of document.getElementsByTagName("input")) {
    if (input.type == "button") { input.addEventListener( "click", do_stuff ); }
  }
}, false );
function pvc(val) {
  var input = document.getElementById("value").value;
  var result = document.getElementById("result");

  if (val == 'inch') {
    result.innerHTML = input / 0.39370;
  } else if (val == 'cm') {
    result.innerHTML = input * 0.39370;
  } else if (val == 'celc') {
    result.innerHTML = 9 / 5 + 32;
  } else if (val == 'fahr') {
    result.innerHTML = (input - 32) * 5 / 9;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Partie 1: Affichage et animation des images</h2>
<div id="radiobuttons">
  <label><input name="vf" type="radio" onclick="changeImage('http://i.imgur.com/0zfjKQi.jpg')" value="0" checked/>Salade</label>
  <br>
  <label><input name="vf" type="radio" onclick="changeImage('http://i.imgur.com/OixGjjE.jpg')" value="1"/>Spaghetti</label><br>
  <label><input name="vf" type="radio" onclick="changeImage('http://i.imgur.com/gASTpLX.jpg')" value="2"/>Creme glacee</label>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
</div>
<img id="food">

<h2>Partie 2: Affichage dans la page web contr&ocirc;l&eacute; par JavaScript</h2>

<form>
  Nom: <input type="text" name="fullname"><br><br> Niveau (1 &aacute; 6): <input type="text" name="niveau">
  <input type="button" value="Afficher partie 2">
</form>

<div class="Affichage">

</div>
<h2>Partie 3: Formulaire de conversion</h2>
Valeur:<input type="text" id="value" name="valeur" value="0">
<p id="result">Resultat ici</p>
<button type="button" id="inchToCm" onclick="pvc('inch')">Pouces vers cm</button>
<button type="button" id="cmtoInch" onclick="pvc('cm')">CM vers pouces</button>
<button type="button" id="celciusToFarenheit" onclick="pvc('celc')">Celcius vers
    Farenheit</button>
<button type="button" id="farenheitToCelcius" onclick="pvc('fahr')">Farenheit vers Celcius</button>
<div id="toggleThis">
  <h2>Partie 4: JQuery (cliquez ici)</h2>
  <div id="partie4">Voici le contenu de la partie 4, cliquez de nouveau sur le titre</div>
```

Comment: Should I be putting the function in a separate page .js or just put the function in HTML? I put it in my html with <script>. The answer is supposed to go to div affichage but nothing is happening, im new to this and really confused im sorry

Comment: thanks a lot it works perfectly, im still wondering why it didnt work for me in the first place when I tried your code tho :p

Comment: Just run the snippet, and you'll see it works. And as for the separate javascript file, it all depends. I usually like to use a separate file to keep things tidy, but a separate file comes with its difficulties. You have to know where and how to define a function, or adding event listeners. But i recommend you learn it. It will be for your benefit.

Comment: Glad it worked. And probably you would need to rewrite the rest of your code in JQuery fashion. It would be faster and tidy.